# Modular arithmetic - competitive programming

Tags: c++, math, modular-arithmetic

I saw a lot of competitive programmers writing code with `((a + b) % d + d) % d` in C++. Why don't they just use `(a + b) % d`? What is that `+ d` inside parentheses good for? Does it have something to do with negative numbers?

Thanks

Comment: "Does it have something to do with negative numbers?" Have you tried using negative numbers with both methods and comparing the answers you get?

Comment: Oh, now I see. I was inattentive when I was trying to come up with answer on my own, sorry. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `((a + b) % d + d) % d`?

Comment: No, it was like I wrote last time I've seen this, but It was probably because of that particular problem input constraints. Your version is more general, isn't it? Thanks, I edited question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Until C++11 the behaviour of the remainder operator `%` for negative arguments was left to the implementation, subject to some constraints. And adding `d` to the left argument can help that so long as the other terms in that argument sum to greater or equal to `-d`, which, in general is not the case. (`-a / d` multiples of `d` for the case of negative `a` would have been a better additive constant in your particular case.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has something to do with negative numbers. It prevents the result from being a negative number under certain conditions. In this case, when the `b` variable is negative, the result of `b % d` is also negative. This result can never be greater than `d`, so adding `d` to this result forces the result to be positive.

Below code is Java code, but it has the same principle:

```
int a = 13;
int b = -23;
int d = 31;

int result1 = (a + b % d + d) % d;
int result2 = (a + b % d) % d;

System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
```

It outputs the following:

```
21
-10
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid integer overflow and to always keep number positive we use modular arithmetic. 
Compettitve programmers tend to use **`(a+b)%b`** instead of **`a%b`** when a is a negative number.

```
a%b = (a+b)%b
(a+b)%b = a%b + b%b = a%b + 0 = a%b
```

Like `a=-2` & `b=5` then `a%b = 3`